# Is it necessary to use antialias when to draw horizontal or vertical line?

Tags: android, drawing

I think anti alias is only useful when drawing circular shape.
It only makes slower when drawing horizontal or vertical line.
So, I don't use paint.setAntiAlias when I do drawLine(...).
Am I right or wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't rotate the line then there's no use in `setAntiAlias`.